# Will using Zee Drive affect the performance of QGIS

Tags: qgis, performance, file-path, sharepoint

At our company we are thinking of moving from a server to our local machines with Sharepoint. 
Zee drive would be implemented to act as an interface for all our files, including our geospatial data. We would then run QGIS of our local machines and "fetch" the data we needed from one of these mapped drives.

I have read that using QGIS with a network drive is not very efficient and I am not sure if QGIS cache's this data. Will this effect rendering speed in QGIS?

Comment: I do not agree that this is primarily opinion based. I have a definitive answer from the developers of Zee Drive.  I need to answer my own question but I don't believe I can because it is on hold.

Answer (score 1):

All our data, including geospatial data, is on a network drive (plain SAMBA) in our organization. We are a small organization (~12 employees) and the others are working on small Excel files, Word documents and writing e-mails. They do not put much pressure on the network and the server (gigabit speed without load balancing). It sure is more efficient to read and write data to/from a local hard drive or better, an SSD. Also, I don't how much overhead Zee drive is adding vs a simple Samba share.

In practice, for what I do here in my day-to-day tasks, I never felt that reading/writing data on the network drive was much of a limitation. I often look at the Window's "Performance monitor" while doing some geoprocessing and the network link is not the bottleneck.

However, if you do a lot of complex and costly operations it may be worth pointing out to your managers that you are not an average computer user like the other employees using Outlook and writing reports on MS Word or whatever. We are talking about maybe gigabytes of network transfer everyday. Your company should consider investing in a proper network infrastructure with load balancing and adding an additional gigabit link for computers working with GIS.

Another thing to point out is data consistency. I don't know Zee Drive at all, but it looks like a mapped drive based on Office 365. My guess is that it syncs with the server once in a while, like google Drive or something. If it doesn't sync real-time and it is a possibility that two employees work on the same data at the same time, you have a problem.

Comment: File syncing can be a problem with shapefiles. Some file-syncing programs will associate one version of the dbf file (attributes) with a different version of the shp file. This can lead to geometries that are associated with the wrong attributes.